# I am using JIRA Python API to create Issue

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using following code to create an issue :

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd
user = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
apikey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
server = 'https://XXXXXXX.atlassian.net'

options = {'server': server}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user,apikey) )

# summary = issue.fields.summary

issue_List=[]

readexcel=pd.read_excel(r'test1.xlsx')
for item in readexcel.index:
 isssue_dict=dict()
 isssue_dict['project']=dict({'key':'MYB'})
 isssue_dict['summary']=readexcel['Summary'][item]
 isssue_dict['description']=readexcel['Description'][item]
 isssue_dict['issuetype']=dict({'name':'Bug'})
 # isssue_dict['customfield_10014']=readexcel['Epic Link'][item]
 isssue_dict['priority']={'name':readexcel['Priority'][item]}
 isssue_dict['labels']=[readexcel['Labels'][item]]
 isssue_dict['reporter'] :dict({'name':readexcel['Reporter'][item]})
 isssue_dict['assignee']=[readexcel['Assignee'][item]]
 new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=isssue_dict)
 print(new_issue._str_())
```

I am not able to put {`versions`:[{`Affects Version\s':Affects version}]} and Epic Link on Jira issue

Comment: so what's the exception return log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the Epic information, please use `add_issues_to_epic(epic_id, issue_keys, ignore_epics=True)`.
If the version already exists, use the keys `versions` and `fixVersions` to set the Affected Version and Fix Version.

See https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html for a full documentation of these methods.